# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 115343360) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in ...\Classes\PHPExcel\CachedObjectStorage\PHPTemp.php on line 65

Tags: php, apache, xampp, phpexcel

Hola soy una usuaria nueva en este mundillo, asi que de antemano mis disculpas si he metido metido la pata en el código. Pero ya tengo varios días desde que trato de leer muchos registros y colocarlos en un archivo de excel, automaticamente me peta el php.

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 125829120) (tried to allocate
>   4096 bytes) in C:\xampp\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php on line 1218

He probado con diferentes opciones disponibles en internet (memory_limit....) y nada.

Caracteristicas del servidor:

- Windows 7/32 bits --Virtual Box
- PHP 7.3.2
- Apache/2.4.38 (Win32) PHP/7.3.2 OpenSSL/1.1.1a
- RAM=4gb, + 4gb virtualizada

Aqui os dejo el código,a gradeceria cualquier ayuda:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G3gn-acEhSLhhYMGVe3FXqTqGSWNHx-4/view?usp=sharing

Un saludo,
Laura

Comment: De cuántos registros hablas? Y como lo estás haciendo? Muchas veces es preferible refactorizar y eliminar cosas que no son necesarias o aplicar unset donde sea necesario que ampliar memory_limit.

Comment: Cargo un archivo Xml que es el archivo bruto que graba N registros x M indicadores, que contiene todas los indicadores que busco. Para esta prueba en cuestion son  10000 x 24. Que es donde me peta el programa

Answer (score 0):

Puedes controlar la cantidad de memoria que usará PHP por medio de PHP ini o configurar en tiempo de ejecución también. Aumentar la cantidad de memoria que puede usar PHP resolverá tu problema.

Para revisar cuánta memoria puede ocupar ejecuta:

```
print_r(ini_get('memory_limit'));
```

Para cambiar la cantidad max que puede ocupar desde `php.ini`:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Si lo haces desde `.htaccess`:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

Y si lo haces en tiempo de ejecución:

```
ini_set(‘memory_limit’,’256MB’);
```